# How to I combine two Tkinter "Files"

Tags: python, tkinter

So I made the Main Menu in one Tkinter File and I made an app in another file. In the main menu, I have a button, when I click that button it should open the app but NOT SHOW THE MAIN MENU.

File 1

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

btn = Button(root, command=#add one later)
```

And in file 2 I have my app and when I click on the button it should open the app and hide the main menu. Can I do this through frames?

NOTE: THE APP IS ANOTHER FILE

Comment: What do you mean _not show the menu_ your already opened your main menu

Comment: Basically frames on the screen, it should show the menu and when I click on the button it should CHANGE the screen to my app.

Comment: You can put your whole code inside of a function and  `import file` and then run that function and use `destroy()` method to remove the menu

Comment: I tried, you can't destroy a parent window.

Comment: But why not? Whats the problem in doing so?

Comment: So basically its not possible to destroy a parent window because then the whole program closes, I can destroy child windows which won't affect anything,

Comment: Also, I want to call them back to each other, so if I click the button on the main menu it should take me to my app. And when I click the back button in my app, it should take me back to the menu.

Comment: Ive added an answer

Comment: Whos Ive, I dont see his or her response anywhere.

Comment: My response, I suppose?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood your question, there could be 2 things that you might be asking, 1st if you want to launch a new window and destroy this, you can call `root.destroy()` followed by calling the other file by using `import file_name` that has another `Tk()`. 2nd if you want to pack/update a `Frame` then make sure that the other file is within a definition which is not called there, also in the second file use the same terminology as you have used in the first file or you can pass these parameters through the function call. Now you can do

```
menu.destroy()
import file_name
file_name.function_name(arguments)
```